# Synchronizing Spinner over two Fragments with ViewPager/TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

this is how my 'app' looks like at the moment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozo9V.jpg
Im trying to synchronize the two spinners, so that when i select an item on the first tab, it will also be selected on the second tab.

I tried communicating via interface and updating the spinner views during onCreateView on the specific fragments, but since the views already get created before the fragment is visible, nothing changes.

Also tried updating the spinner's selected item when the fragment becomes visible by overriding setUserVisibleHint, it works but doesnt look good at all, because there's a delay between the swipe and the updating of the spinner.

Is it possible to synchronize the two spinners in a way that the item in Fragment 2's spinner is already set when i swipe over from Fragment 1? Should work both ways.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use setArguments and getArguments in order to get data before inflating fragment.

Here is sample code:

Parent Class :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
fragment1 = new Fragment1();
bundle.putString("key1","messageContent");
fragment1.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment Class :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String x;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle = getArguments();
    x= bundle.getString("key1");
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Communicating the data from fragment to fragment is not my problem, it's more the fact how to update the other fragments spinner without having a noticable delay. setUserVisibleHint/getUserVisibleHint really sucks, because you literally can see the new fragment already after swiping before it returns true. Also can't use onCreate/onCreateView because fragments only get inflated once and not every time i swipe.